read() after write() does not read what I just wrote
I am learning to deal with files in C. Now i try to use read() and write() correctly. So I wrote the following code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(){
    [...]
    write(fd, "Hallo", 5);
    printf("Value before:");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%c", buf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    reading = read(fd, buf, 5);
    printf("%d\n", reading);
    printf("Value after:");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%c", buf[i]);
    }
    [...]
}

The program should open the given file, write "Hallo" into it and read the text in the file. As output there should be a text "Value before:" with the inside of the empty buffer (so nothing i guess?), then the amount of the read characters (the value reading) and last a line with "Value after:" and behind it the read word "Hallo".
My problem: The only outputs i do get from this code are the lines where it is written "Value before:" and "Value after:" and between these both lines there is output the value of reading. But the Value of reading is 0 every time. And the text which should be there behind "Value after" (see second for-loop) isn't there. As I output the written in of the file (by using cat) there is output "Hallo".
As the conclusion the problem must be the read()-function, so that it doesn't read the file. But I don't know why. I think the syntax is right.
I hope you are able to help me.

Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. We don't see you open the file or initialize buf  anywhere.

Also please note that write and read are really POSIX (i.e. macOS or Linux) functions. C have its own set of functions for reading and writing files (fopen(), fread(), fwrite(), etc.).

You need to seek back to the beginning of the file if you want to read what you just wrote.

I see you have skipped what you probably consider to be a lot of unnecessary detail, but there are two other pieces of information that might be useful. One is your invocation of open(). It would be useful to see what flags you passed. The other is your declaration and initialisation of buf.

Another option is to use pread and/or pwrite which have a file offset parameter that specifies where to read or write from. These functions do not change the current seek position.

The POSIX file functions maintain a concept of a "current file offset". You can query and modify this offset using the lseek() function. (Documentation here.) When you read or write data, the current offset gets automagically moved at the end of the data that you just read or wrote.
This is necessary so that a subsequent invocation of write() will append data to the file, instead of overwriting what you previously wrote.  This is also how multiple successive invocations of read() will keep reading more and more data from the file, instead of the same data.
So, after you have written "Hallo", the current offset is at the end of "Hallo". If you try reading data at that moment, you will of course read nothing, because the current offset is already at the end of the file.
To correct this, you have to either:

Close and re-open the file.
Use lseek() to seek to the beginning of the file.

Then, your next read() will read "Hallo".
